# Stuck on render ring in fullscreen when having used `xrendr -o right`

Tags: 13.10, lubuntu, java, fullscreen

At work I am supposed to get a Java application running in fullscreen on a big-screen tv. This TV is connected to a **Intel Nuc** device, which is running **Lubuntu 13.10**.

This TV is hanging on the wall and is tilted. If you turn your head 90 degrees left then you will look at the TV "normally".

To compensate for this, I have edited the `[XRandr]` section of  `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/desktop.conf` in the following way:

```
[XRandr]
mode=command
command=xrandr -o right
```

This causes the screen to be more readable by all humans that are keeping their feet on their ground and their head up (but still looking straight forward).

However, when I start a Java application that is showing, the X handler freezes. I can move the mouse but not use it. I can't seem to use the keyboard in any way except switching to a TTY. The TTYs output these error messages on different intervals:

- Stuck on render ring (most common, about once every 3 seconds)
- Render ring stuck inside bo (quite common, perhaps once every 30 seconds)
- Timed out waiting for forcewake old ack to clear (very rare, but still seem to happpen sometimes)

For completeness sake, here is the Java code I am running to show the application in full screen:

```
    GraphicsDevice[] devices = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices();
    frame.setVisible(false);
    frame.dispose();
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    GraphicsDevice device = devices[0];

    Rectangle rect = device.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
    frame.setBounds(rect.x, rect.y, rect.height, rect.width); // width and height have switched places because of the display being rotated
    device.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

(This code is from an SO question about how to show a JFrame in full screen)

I have tried installing new drivers, `Intel(R) Graphics Installer 1.0.4 for Linux*` from https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads (`Graphics Installer for Ubuntu* 13.10, 32-bit`). This doesn't help :(

The thing is that when **not changing desktop.conf**, the Java application works perfectly well in full screen. So it seems to be related to the `xrandr -o right` command.

Any ideas, suggestions, thoughts appreciated.